# "in dict" always false

Tags: python, dictionary

`node in children` is always false
but in the debugger:

```
(pdb) children.keys()
...
turn: 1, last: (5, 2), hash: 5837165650205296398,
...
(pdb) node
turn: 1, last: (5, 2), hash: 5837165650205296398
(pdb) node in children
False
(pdb) node.__eq__(node)
True
```

heres the function.

```py
def _select(node):
    path = []
    global new, terminals, found
    while True:
        path.append(node)
        if node not in children: new += 1;return path
        if not children[node]: terminals += 1;return path;
        unexplored = children[node] - children.keys()
        if unexplored:
            found += 1
            n = unexplored.pop() # ignore best path?
            path.append(n)
            return path
        # node = _uct_select(node)
        else: node = choice(tuple(children[unexplored]))
```

and here's the **hash**() and  **eq**() functions

```py
    def __hash__(self):
        "Nodes must be hashable"
        return hash(tuple(self.board.flatten() ))

    def __eq__(node1, node2):
        "Nodes must be comparable"
        return node1.board is node2.board
```

board is just a [6,7] array

Comment: It seems unlikely your nodes are equal, as I don't think `node1.board is node2.board` would be true - however, it is impossible to tell without knowing more about how nodes are constructed.

Comment: Did you really mean `node1.board is node2.board` rather than `node1.board == node2.board`?

Comment: @Amadan it does produce true though. I've added that to the question

Comment: @Thomas using "==" produces a boolean array, whereas "is" produces a single boolean

Comment: Of course `node.__eq__(node)`. Construct two _different but equal_ nodes and try it. e.g. `foo = object(); foo is foo` has a very different semantics than `object() is object()`.

Comment: @Amadan but ``__eq__()`` only checks the board, and ``__hash()__`` only uses the board, so it's not possible for ``__eq__()`` to be false if they have the same board. I assume that ``in dict`` uses ``__eq__()``?

Comment: @Thomas it doesn't return a boolean array, since I used ``board is board`` instead of ``board == board``. the latter creates an array

Comment: You are using `is` check. That means `__eq__` will be true only if the two have the _same_ board, not if they have the _different but identical_ board. To reiterate my example from before, `[1, 2] is [1, 2]` returns false.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing from your question and comments that `node.board` is a numpy array; it would have helped if you had mentioned that explicitly. The `==` operator (i.e. `__eq__()`) on numpy arrays indeed has some surprising behaviour: it returns a numpy array of booleans, rather than a single boolean.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2])
>>> b = np.array([1, 2])
>>> a == b
array([ True,  True])
```

But the `is` operator can't be used as an alternative, because these two arrays are not the same object:

```
>>> a is b
False
```

So in this case, you need to use `numpy.array_equal(node1.board, node2.board)`:

```
>>> np.array_equal(a, b)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your  `eq` function. unless they are the exact same list ie. their object ids are equal `is` will return false. `is` is not the same as `==`

```
board_b  = [6,7]
board_a  = [6,7]

print(board_a is board_b)
print(board_a == board_b)
```

prints

```
False
True
```

see [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)  for lots more info on subject

Comment: how would I get a single boolean, instead of a boolean array? and does that mean I couldn't use ``is None`` if they are different objects either?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that question. when are you getting an array of bools?

Comment: I'm using ``some_object is None`` to see if an object is ``NoneType`` elsewhere in my code. would this always produce ``False`` if the ``NoneType`` object and ``None`` are different objects?

Comment: `is None`  is fine and is normal to use.  None is keyword and functions like a singleton .  `None is None` will always be true